# ExtJs multiline input

Tags: javascript, extjs

How do i create a multiline input with vertical scrollbars in EXTJS?

I used this

```
 noteField = new Ext.form.TextField({
                emptyText: 'note...',
                multiline: true,
                applyTo: 'txtNote',
                maxLength: 250
            });

            noteField.setSize(200, 100);
```

but the input is not multiline...

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 10):

You need to be using:

```
 Ext.form.TextArea()
```

Like so:

```
 var noteField = new Ext.form.TextArea({
      //config here    
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'About you',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'Name',
                name: 'name'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textareafield',
                label: 'Bio',
                maxRows: 4,
                name: 'bio'
            }]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextArea` instead of `TextField`. I have also faced the same issue. This code snippet works for me:

```
editor: new Ext.form.TextArea({

})
```